# Add percent value in mvc3 pie chart

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, charts

I'm currently using microsoft's webhelper plugin, and I'm using the Chart object. I've noticed that the pie chart doesn't have a percentage value like the one from jqplot:

http://www.jqplot.com/tests/pie-donut-charts.php

Is it possible to add percent value in the pie chart?

Thanks

czetsuya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I chose to implement a Chart using a third party library JQPlot, it's much easier this way. Note that there are other 3rd party chart libraries out there like high charts.